Problem running native query projections with UUID in spring-data repository on kotlin and h2 in Unit Tests
Given the following kotlin code, I get an exception when running the test (see last code snippet), saying:
Cannot project byte[] to java.util.UUID; Target type is not an interface and no matching Converter found

This occurs as soon as the test tries to access the id property of the projection and it happens ONLY in test where I use h2 as an embedded in-memory database.
Running the code on a real environment with postgres works.
It's probably an issue with the way h2 stores the UUID or how the driver delivers it. Maybe that's different to how postgres handles this. Or there are Converters missing in the in the ConversionService when running in test mode.
I've created a complete test project which you can find on github
I did not try adding a custom converter yet because I thought the conversion from byte[] to UUID would be be standard behavior and I just forgot to add some configuration.
@Repository
interface CustomRepository : JpaRepository<CustomEntity, UUID> {

    @Query("select id from CUSTOM_ENTITY_TABLE", nativeQuery = true)
    fun nativeProjectingQuery() : List<CustomProjection>
}

where the entity looks like this
@Table(name = "CUSTOM_ENTITY_TABLE")
@Entity
data class CustomEntity (
    @Id
    val id: UUID,
    val someData : String
){}

and the projection like this
interface CustomProjection {
    var id : UUID
}

the following test
@DataJpaTest
class CustomRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired private lateinit var customRepository: CustomRepository

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val result = customRepository.nativeProjectingQuery()
        assertThat(result[0].id).isNotNull()
    }
}

EDIT: I called the projection from within the main method of the spring app and tried to println the id of the projection: The same error occurs. (changed the code on github accordingly)

Both PostgreSQL and H2 have built-in non-standard UUID data types and official JDBC drivers of these database systems support storage and retrieval of their values via java.util.UUID objects (in case of PgJDBC this class needs to be explicitly specified for retrieval, H2 uses it by default), no conversion is necessary. You have a problem somewhere on JPA level.

Looks like this is actually an hibernate/JPA thing.
Just implemented a custom repository with a ResultTransformer. The data passed TupleTransformer already contains a byte[]/ByteArray for the UUID field.
At that point I can solve the issue by implementing the conversion myself like this;
val id = pIdDB as? UUID
                    ?: (pIdDB as? ByteArray)?.let { bytes -> val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes); UUID(byteBuffer.getLong(), byteBuffer.getLong()) }
                    ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unexpected type for ID")

But that doesn't solve my issue
